# stop printing na in plot

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting a categorical variable. There is no `NA` but the plot is coming up with `NA` bar with no observation in it. How do I stop prinint this `NA` ber in my plot?

```
ggplot(data.frame(cat.hour), 
       aes(x=factor(cat.hour, levels=c("1 min","2 min","3 min","4 min","5 min","6 min","7 min","8 min","9 min","10 min")))) + 
  geom_bar(fill="lightgreen")
```

[image]

Comment: Where did you read about this type of syntax for `ggplot` calls? My suggestion would be to get back to the drawing board and read some examples of [geom_bar](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html).

Comment: Can you please show the output of `unique(cat.hour)`? It seems likely that you are not being exhaustive in your list of levels and hence you are creating NAs. Something like `factor(1:4, levels = 1:3)`

Comment: `cat.hour=cut(hour,breaks= seq(0,10,by= 1),labels=c("1 min","2 min","3 min","4 min","5 min","6 min","7 min","8 min","9 min","10 min"))
             cat.hour=factor(cat.hour)`

This is how I converted my vector into a categorical one.
and the `unique` comment gives me...this: 

`unique(cat.hour)
 [1] 5 min  3 min  9 min  8 min  6 min  4 min  7 min  2 min  1 min  10 min <NA>  
Levels: 1 min 2 min 3 min 4 min 5 min 6 min 7 min 8 min 9 min 10 min `

Comment: To second Gregor: Are there any values less 0 or greater 10 in `hour`? What does `range(hour)` return?

Comment: Nope.............`time <- time[!time %in% 0]
hour=time[time<=10]`

Comment: I have asked to post the result of `range(hour)` because it would have immediately shown the presence of NA in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in call `unique(cat.hour)` there is an NA in your data.

Filtering for non-NA values would be a simple workaround for your plot. However, I encourage you to perform your calculations outside of the plot.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)

cat.hour %>%
   na.omit() %>%
   mutate(variable = factor(variable, levels=c("1 min","2 min","3 min","4 min","5 min","6 min","7 min","8 min","9 min","10 min"))) -> cat.hour

g <- ggplot(cat.hour, aes(x = variable))
g <- g + geom_bar(fill = "lightgreen")
g
```

Comment: Thank you.... 
It's helpful .........but I had issues with `Inf` .......which I got to fix and it's working.

Comment: Thx for the accept!

Finding the bug is always better than a workaround :)